# UpdateInterval doesn't work with Dynamic[CurrentImage]

Tags: image-processing, dynamic

I work on image processing using images from webcams. It's connected via USB and I get "live" images by:

```
Dynamic[Refresh[CurrentImage[], UpdateInterval->5]]
```

but the `UpdateInterval` option doesn't affect the frequency of image updating.
How to make `Dynamic` get images from webcams with a specific time interval? There is `ImageCapture` function with a `FrameRate` option and it works fine, but functionality of `ImageCapture`looks excessive for me (I only need an image).

Comment: [Related conversation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52621514) in site's chat.

Comment: This appears to happen because CurrentImage has its own internal Refresh to allow for Dynamic[CurrentImage[]] shorthand. The discussion in chat linked above has a workable solution that I have now used in production (ie, an art exhibition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is by setting the framerate on the device.

```
dev = First@FindDevices["Camera"]

DeviceConfigure[dev, "FrameRate" -> 1/5]

Dynamic[CurrentImage[]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just came across the same problem in my code. Here is a workaround:

```
capt[dt_] := Block[{},
  Pause[dt];
  CurrentImage[]
  ]


Dynamic[capt[.1]]
```

Unfortunately, the drawback is that for large sleep times (>0.5seconds) it really slows down the Mathematica notebook (I think it's a side effect of Pause)